# Cosmos DB dedicated Gatewat connection

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have been facing an issue while trying to query data from the cosmos DB gateway,
the issue happens when I use the connection string provided for the Gateway and sends a request to fetch data from the database it gets fetched the first time but if the request is executed again it returns an encrypted error
but the quiring works fine when using the regular connection string

here is the config where I get the connection string :[the cosmos keys][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQIuS.png

this is one of the queries I used:

```
    const getEventById = async ({ id }) => {
      const querySpec = {
        query:
          'SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.id = @eventId', 
        parameters: [
          {
            name: '@eventId',
            value: id,
          },
        ],
      }

  const { resources: results } = await database.container(db.containersIds.EVENT).items.query(querySpec).fetchAll()
  return results[0]
}
```

and here is the response I get back

> 48,29,6,3,85,29,14,4,22,4,20,255,164,47,109,4,138,212,99,82,39,177,204,57,31,30,154,53,16,129,157,48,14,6,3,85,29,15,1,1,255,4,4,3,2,4,176,48,91,6,3,85,29,17,4,84,48,82,130,27,42,46,110,111,116,101,98,111,111,107,46,99,111,115,109,111,115,46,97,122,117,114,101,46,99,111,109,130,23,42,46,115,113,108,120,46,99,111,115,109,111,115,46,97,122,117,114,101,46,99,111,109,130,26,42,46,103,114,101,109,108,105,110,46,99,111,115,109,111,115,46,97,122,117,114,101,46,99,111,109,48,129,176,6,3,85,29,31,4,129,168,48,129,165,48,129,162,160,129,159,160,129,156,134,77,104,116,116,112,58,47,47,109,115,99,114,108,46,109,105,99,114,111,115,111,102,116,46,99,111,109,47,112,107,105,47,109,115,99,111,114,112,47,99,114,108,47,77,105,99,114,111,115,111,102,116,37,50,48,82,83,65,37,50,48,84,76,83,37,50,48,67,65,37,50,48,48,49,46,99,114,108,134,75,104,116,116,112,58,47,47,99,114,108,46,109,105,99,114,111,115,111,102,116,46,99,111,109,47,112,107,105,47,109,115,99,111,114,112,47,99,114,108,47,77,105,99,114,111,115,111,102,116,37,50,48,82,83,65,37,50,48,84,76,83,37,50,48,67,65,37,50,48,48,49,46,99,114,108,48,87,6,3,85,29,32,4,80,48,78,48,66,6,9,43,6,1,4,1,130,55,42,1,48,53,48,51,6,8,43,6,1,5,5,7,2,1,22,39,104,116,116,112,58,47,47,119,119,119,46,109,105,99,114,111,115,111,102,116,46,99,111,109,47,112,107,105,47,109,115,99,111,114,112,47,99,112,115,48,8,6,6,103,129,12,1,2,1,48,31,6,3,85,29,35,4,24,48,22,128,20,181,118,12,48,17,206,199,146,66,77,76,199,92,44,200,169,12,232,11,100,48,29,6,3,85,29,37,4,22,48,20,6,8,43,6,1,5,5,7,3,1,6,8,43,6,1,5,5,7,3,2,48,13,6,9,42,134,72,134,247,13,1,1,11,5,0,3,130,2,1,0,4,232,247,149,202,202,168,231,182,243,138,50,179,190,236,18,93,244,155,139,31,75,238,162,150,134,206,36,22,123,43,222,113,130,195,128,71,109,145,135,187,175,225,43,15,86,184,152,207,209,103,160,220,194,232,51,136,163,222,151,241,41,208,200,224,191,135,79,240,52,89,248,142,185,235,227,192,239,242,213,192,49,56,245,105,216,6,50,53,33,98,129,116,237,26,75,196,79,213,142,28,142,46,40,254,98,143,142,177,199,173,158,189,215,100,65,14,126,144,15,55,123,251,140,67,152,37,68,183,193,70,172,44,164,233,245,179,19,205,157,52,127,48,141,129,18,223,110,120,175,27,97,143,94,246,62,32,96,99,148,235,22,4,99,218,235,93,225,74,89,244,174,127,125,96,72,55,238,14,200,218,13,67,59,95,190,48,32,59,77,163,153,57,5,153,218,205,33,86,161,253,255,91,152,75,199,48,201,191,242,92,226,74,207,152,135,90,35,74,90,57,107,177,175,102,16,81,109,72,219,211,2,35,210,14,233,208,99,143,178,28,60,54,128,169,64,49,42,23,236,75,60,99,184,85,100,214,30,84,82,86,226,248,159,138,180,123,245,26,51,215,209,82,209,174,54,43,191,7,19,18,27,106,224,93,205,147,228,255,10,6,111,42,74,151,51,8,225,79,166,220,154,217,232,9,205,26,2,14,87,78,98,241,113,160,64,18,25,53,203,165,80,177,14,197,52,89,170,220,34,128,156,98,82,57,75,233,147,194,85,205,223,93,112,107,25,4,147,22,80,141,197,203,188,60,118,159,187,7,246,27,13,86,91,108,200,217,135,98,56,7,103,226,156,79,227,37,221,111,134,190,218,34,53,146,132,171,187,114,52,137,177,40,236,5,110,79,27,59,217,104,231,95,212,214,15,60,41,168,198,1,71,62,112,153,76,153,194,229,105,46,69,233,42,189,179,95,25,220,93,130,28,198,95,33,180,243,142,191,101,15,134,95,52,54,2,123,197,10,214,117,5,43,181,123,127,73,252,229,101,207,219,27,206,146,61,4,122,166,170,25,176,225,136,250,118,68,189,166,79,7,29,255,180,203,160,180,20,221,93,63,151,85,90,25,95,77,200,225,155,193,211,48,85,79,251,122,151,22,219,93,20,164,2,4,0,173,3,2,1,1
> ]
> }
> },
> "list": [
> "socketURI:443::::::::true:::::::::::::",
> "socketURI:443::::::::true:::::::::::::"
> ]
> }
> }   },   "headers": {
> "x-ms-throttle-retry-count": "REDACTED",
> "x-ms-throttle-retry-wait-time-ms": "REDACTED"   },   "message": "read ECONNRESET" }

as for the rest of the error, it was off the terminal so I couldn't get it

Comment: Not really enough information to go on here. Can you include all of the error text? Can you also show the code used to run the query. Also unlikely the service is returning an encrypted error as these would be useless to a user for troubleshooting.

Comment: Any chance you can catch for exceptions and pipe the exception message into a file so you can capture it? The most useful part here is probably what's fallen outside your terminal window.

Comment: I have changed the connection method from providing an options object with the connection key and URL to providing a connection string which solved the problem and the dedicated Gateway started behaving in a normal way
so thanks for the help